# Remove bogus DNS from resolvectl status

Tags: dns, systemd-resolved, openconnect

I use openconnect to join a VPN. On disconnection, the DNS remain alongside with mine in Global section, which causes a delay in network queries :

```
Global
         Protocols: -LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
  resolv.conf mode: foreign
Current DNS Server: 172.29.183.69
       DNS Servers: 172.29.183.69 172.29.183.70 192.168.100.144
        DNS Domain: groumpf.org in.company.fr

Link 2 (enp2s0f0)
Current Scopes: none
     Protocols: -DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported

Link 4 (wlp3s0)
Current Scopes: none
     Protocols: -DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported

Link 5 (docker0)
Current Scopes: none
     Protocols: -DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported

Link 6 (vmnet1)
Current Scopes: none
     Protocols: -DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported

Link 7 (vmnet8)
Current Scopes: none
     Protocols: -DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported

Link 9 (enx482ae3a900cd)
Current Scopes: none
     Protocols: -DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
```

groumpf.org/192.168.100.144 are my correct domain/DNS, while others are remnants from tun0 wich is actuallay down.

The system is Ubuntu 21.10 (kinetics) and openconnect is 9.01. Is this a systemd or an openconnect problem ?

Regards, Xavier